# using hollow wall anchor in double plasterboard

Tags: drywall, drywall-anchor

I'm trying to put up a wall-mounted wine rack. My house is terraced and the wall on which I'm trying to put it on is the one between the two houses. On the internal side of the wall there is plasterboard and then some insulation.

Initially I thought that this would be the typical 1/2" thick plasterboard (as it is for the internal partition walls in the house) but it turns out it's 1.25"-1.5" thick. After closer inspection I noticed that there is a 1/2" thick plasterboard and then another thicker sheet of plasterboard (?), so the two sheets together end up being 1.25"-1.5" thick.

I have already put a hollow wall anchor which is for 1/2" thick plasterboard, so I understand that the metal sleeve will have expanded into the second, thicker plasterboard. Can this cause any kind of problem? Is it safe to continue putting the rest of the hollow wall anchors the same way?

Answer (score 1):

If the first one is already set in place I would probably leave it alone, especially if the additional anchors will be sharing the load.

I **would not** continue using additional anchors of the same type, they are not designed for that wall thickness. You should procure some appropriate anchors, such as toggle bolts or **long** molly anchors:

[image][image][image]

Comment: I would probably use E-Z drywall anchors. They hold really well and can be removed at a later date. I agree with jimmy on the first one and would probably leave it in place if expanded.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very good solution for what you are trying to accomplish, they can hold a lot of weight and are not subject to just compression. Basically you drill your pilot hole sized to the shank, not the threads! This will make an easier and cleaner install - you don't need to but I do it.

Insert the anchor until the threads are at the drywall - screw the anchor into the wall using a cross point screw driver until you are flush with the drywall surface. Then you can use the screws to fasten your wine rack to the wall.

E-Z Ancor Twist-N-Lock Drywall Anchors.

[image: E-Z Ancor Twist-N-Lock Drywall Anchors]

Comment: EZ Anchor packaging specifically states 'Up to 5/8" drywall'